# Why would my MacBook Pro be setup in a port forward in my LAN?

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, port-forwarding

I came across my computer in the port forwarding area of my LAN at my parents house. I did not set this up and am concerned that it’s being used to spy on my computer. I’m not a super user but I know enough to know it’s suspicious but not enough to really be able to determine for sure that’s the case. My dad is very computer savvy and has a desktop and laptop. Do port forwards have to be setup by a person? I’m just trying to understand how it got there and what the most likely purpose of it is. I’m aware that Remote Desktop is the #1 way most users do this but if one was trying to access my computer without there being obvious signs (or firewall restrictions) I’m aware that SSH can bypass the firewall. Also I noticed in WINS that a home group is named although I did not set this up and am unable to remove it because it was setup with the admin account. I know how to secure my device but I’m just trying to get some realistic feedback because I don’t have the knowledge to really assume without feeling a tad paranoid. What do you guys think

Comment: what port is forwarded?

Comment: To "your computer" or to "your IP"? Are the IPs bound to a MAC or are they reused after the lease from the DHCP expires? Maybe s.o. else set it up and you just happen to get the IP from the DHCP?!

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be normal.

If you have Skype or some other VOIP programs then they can use [UPNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) to request that the router open and forward a specific port to your machine, so it *can* be perfectly normal. Games might also use UPNP, as might Bittorrent clients or other programs.

By doing this their connections can be fully peer-to-peer rather than requiring all data to be sent via a third-party server.

If you can see what port is being forwarded to your machine in the router then you can find out what program is listening on your machine.

For Mac you can read [How can I list my open network ports with netstat?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117644/how-can-i-list-my-open-network-ports-with-netstat) which gives some options of how to get the port that is listening.  Specifically `sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` will potentially show you the port and what program has it open.

For Windows

```
netstat -ab
```

will list the ports that are open and what program is listening, so you can see for yourself if it is a program you expect to need internet connections to be made to it.